# Can you place a draw 2 (+2) on top of a draw 4 (+4) in regular Uno?

Tags: uno

So, the way I've always played you can't add a draw 2 on a draw 4 but I've seen plenty of other people do it. So I'm wondering if you can or can't?

Answer (score 4):

You can as long as it's your turn and the color of your **Draw 2** matches the color specified by the player who played the **Draw 4**. In standard Uno rules, the player after the one who played the **Draw 4** will draw the 4 cards, and the player after that one gets the next turn. So, you would need to be the player next to the player next to the one who played the **Draw 4** to play your **Draw 2** (again, assuming it's the correct color). The player after you would draw 2 cards, and it would be the next player's turn.

An example from @JoeW: player 1 plays a **Draw 4** and calls red, player 2 draws 4 cards, player 3 plays a red **Draw 2**, player 4 draws 2 card and play continues as normal.

Answer (score 4):

### Be extremely cautious about what you mean here.

If you're referring to the "Progressive UNO" House Rules variant, then it depends on exactly how you've defined the house rules.

If you refer to standard rules, nothing prevents a +2 from being played on a +4, provided that it is your turn and you match the color chosen (matching the number is not possible, since +4 and +2 are not the same number).

Comment: I don't think this is referring to house rules but normal rules and the next card being a draw 2.

Comment: Based on OP's phrase *"add a draw 2 on a draw 4"* I think it is likely they are talking about progressive UNO.